# Reusing subqueries in AWS Athena generate large amount of data scanned

Tags: subquery, amazon-athena, presto

On AWS Athena, I am trying to reuse computed data using a WITH clause, e.g.

```
WITH temp_table AS (...)
SELECT ...
FROM temp_table t0, temp_table t1, temp_table t2
WHERE ...
```

If the query is fast, the "Data scanned" goes through the roof. As if `temp_table` is computed for each time it is reference in the `FROM` clause.

I don't see the issue if I create a temp table separately and use it multiple times in the query.

Is there a way to really reuse a subquery multiple times without any penalty?

Comment: Unfortunately this is how inline views work in Presto. This is tracked as https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/10

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I was hoping to avoid creating temp tables and perform the whole operation in one single SQL query. But it seems like Presto won't let me do it.

Comment: Don't think of them as temp tables, that you create for a single query and then delete them. Athena is not a standard DB with a single node, indexes, and lots of RAM in that instance. It is a distributed compute engine that scans hundreds of files in various locations. Analyze your queries and design the paths of aggregation, partition and other optimization that you can reuse in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temp table using CTAS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/ctas.html) instead of using WITH. The temp table can use Parquet format as an example, which can reduce the data scanned in the next queries assuming they don't use all columns. It also prevents large memory consumption which may result in "Query exhausted" errors